# Using imageview by url in android

Tags: android, inputstream, android-imageview

I try to get a photo from a url but i could not get the photo.

Current Code:

```
public class IndexActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage("http://www.gophoto.it/view.php?i=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2LTvCCufBKc/T3L3KgcTj2I/AAAAAAAABbQ/Ki60e1LU9sE/s1600/Sachin%2BTendulkar.png");
    i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }
    return in;
}

private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
    }
}
```

**and this the the locCat :**

```
08-01 08:53:17.818: D/ActivityThread(12315): handleResumeActivity now pri:0
08-01 08:53:17.818: D/ActivityThread(12315): handleResumeActivity set pri:0
08-01 08:53:20.268: W/System.err(12315): java.io.IOException: Error connecting
08-01 08:53:20.268: W/System.err(12315):    at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.IndexActivity.OpenHttpConnection(IndexActivity.java:70)
08-01 08:53:20.268: W/System.err(12315):    at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.IndexActivity.DownloadImage(IndexActivity.java:79)
08-01 08:53:20.268: W/System.err(12315):    at tr.com.turkcell.shmobile.IndexActivity.onCreate(IndexActivity.java:32)
08-01 08:53:20.268: W/System.err(12315):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-01 08:53:20.268: W/System.err(12315):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
08-01 08:53:20.268: W/System.err(12315):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-01 08:53:20.268: W/System.err(12315):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-01 08:53:20.268: W/System.err(12315):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-01 08:53:20.268: W/System.err(12315):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-01 08:53:20.278: W/System.err(12315):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 08:53:20.278: W/System.err(12315):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 08:53:20.278: W/System.err(12315):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4754)
08-01 08:53:20.278: W/System.err(12315):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 08:53:20.278: W/System.err(12315):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 08:53:20.278: W/System.err(12315):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
08-01 08:53:20.278: W/System.err(12315):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-01 08:53:20.278: W/System.err(12315):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 08:53:20.278: D/ActivityThread(12315): handleResumeActivity now pri:0
08-01 08:53:20.278: D/ActivityThread(12315): handleResumeActivity set pri:0
```

Comment: Have you try different url? The one in your code is wrong. It should be look like this `http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2LTvCCufBKc/T3L3KgcTj2I/AAAAAAAABbQ/Ki60e1LU9sE/s1600/Sachin%2BTendulkar.png`

Comment: I have tried different url but it didnt change anything

Comment: The logcat isn't useful because your `throw new IOException("Error connecting");` hides the original exception. Either remove that `catch` block altogether or pass the original `ex` to the newly created `IOException` constructor.

Comment: Use Asynctask for Http connection.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is calling long running task on main UI thread.

Use `AsynckTask`'s `onPostExecute` method for downloaded image bitmap. Bind your `ImageView` object with the returned bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

**Try out this Simple one:**

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Its online getting so Check your Internet Permission:

add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Tutorial for Android Image Loading from URL:

Try : [this code will be helpful to you](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)

Answer (score 0):

There are following possibilities  regarding to Load Image

1- Image is Protected with **Basic Authentication**

2- URL is invalid

1st change the URL to confirm that your action is perfect and you will see image.

In second scenario i will suggest you to use [AQUERY (Android Query)](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/)
Download the latest jar add it to your project and use in such a way to by pass the basic Authentication

```
private AQuery mAquery;
mAquery=new AQuery(context);
BasicHandle handle = new BasicHandle("Username", "password");
mAquery.id(YourImageView).auth(handle).image(ImagePath,true,true,400,0,null,0,0.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loadImage("http://relinjose.com/directory/filename.png");
```

Here you go

```
void loadImage(String image_location) {
    URL imageURL = null;
    if (image_location != null) {
        try {
            imageURL = new URL(image_location);         
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);// Convert to bitmap
            ivdpfirst.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        //set any default
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the well written `UrlImageViewHelper` library:

https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

The usage is simple:

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imageView, "http://example.com/image.png");
```